# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'get_type' using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I am trying to use the website codes I scraped in a previous script residing within my csv file in order to create urls I can scrape through using xpath. The values are within the "link" column within the csv. I am running into the following errors specifically at line 32

```
File "Willisp3.py", line 32, in <module>
uClient = uReq(url)
File "/Users/gil/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 154, in 
urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/Users/gil/anaconda/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 421, in 
open
protocol = req.get_type()
File "/Users/gil/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-
packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2970, in __getattr__
return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'get_type'
```

Here is my code

```
`filename = 'links.csv'
 df = pd.read_csv(filename)
 imdbcode = df['link']


 for index, row in df.iterrows():
    url = ('https://www.imdb.com/title/' + imdbcode + '/reviews?ref_=tt_urv')
    uClient = uReq(url)
    content = uClient.read()
    uClient.close()
    page_soup = soup(content, "html.parser")
    page_soup = soup(content, "lxml-xml")
    page = requests.get(url)
    stuff2 = html.fromstring(page.content)
    comment = stuff2.xpath('//div[@id="tn15content"]/p/text()')[0]
    title = stuff2.xpath('//div[@id="tn15title"]/h1/a/text()')`
```

Comment: What's line 32? Why don't you show us the whole traceback.

Comment: Just added it in. I apologize for not having it in at first.

Comment: The error is on the function `uReq`, but `uReq` isn't defined or imported anywhere in your code.

Comment: I had uReq defined as  "from urllib2 import urlopen as uReq"

Comment: Thanks. That function takes as input a string or a Requests object. Looks like you provided it something else. What is the output of `type(imdbcode)`?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `url` is a series, not a string. When you initialize `imdbcode`, it is a series of links, and pandas will broadcast the string addition across each row when you start it up.

I can't know for sure without seeing the other stuff, but you want

```
url = 'https://http://www.imdb.com/title/' + row['link'] + '/reviews?ref_=tt_urv'
```

instead to just grab the string value.

Comment: Hey @GilbertLee, glad it worked out for you. If you wouldn't mind accepting my answer I'd appreciate it